# insert values and use inner join where logged in user is

Tags: php, mysql

i'm new to php and mysql, and i'm trying to register a company for the logged in user, this is my atempt i dont know what i'm doing wrong

```
<?php


$sql = "INSERT INTO company (company_name , company_number , company_address, company_email, company_city, company_zip , company_type, company_message) 
    VALUES ('$company_name', '$company_number' , '$company_address' , '$company_email' , '$company_city' , '$company_zip' , '$company_type', '$company_message')
    SELECT company_name , company_number , company_address, company_email, company_city, company_zip , company_type, company_message 
    FROM company INNER JOIN users ON users.company_id = company.company_id WHERE user = '" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'   ";


?>
```

and this is my company and users tables

**company table**

[image]

**users table**

[image]

**EDIT**

i deleted company_id from users table and added userID to the company table and changed my sql query to this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO company (company_name , company_number , company_address, company_email, company_city, company_zip , company_type, company_message) 
SELECT company_name , company_number , company_address, company_email, company_city, company_zip , company_type, company_message
FROM company INNER JOIN users ON company.userID = users.id WHERE users.id = '" . $_SESSION['user']['id'] . "' 
VALUES ('$company_name', '$company_number' , '$company_address' , '$company_email' , '$company_city' , '$company_zip' , '$company_type', '$company_message' )";
```

but i still get an error whenever i try to insert data..
this is the error in full

Error: INSERT INTO company (company_name , company_number , company_address, company_email, company_city, company_zip , company_type, company_message) SELECT company_name , company_number , company_address, company_email, company_city, company_zip , company_type, company_message FROM company INNER JOIN users ON company.userID = users.id WHERE users.id = '31' VALUES ('test', '123' , 'test' , 'test@gmail.com' , 'test' , '123' , 'test', ' test' ) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES ('test', '123' , 'test' , 'test@gmail.com' , 'test' , '123' , 'test', ' t' at line 4

any ideas on how to write my query the right way?

Comment: On the companies table you should have userID as foreign key that rerences users' userID

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](https://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavours from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: Tip: Having prefixes like `company_` on every single field can become extremely annoying to deal with almost immediately as it makes what should be a simple query suddenly very, very verbose.